# octave plot FMT argument not respected

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

I'm trying to plot a 2D dataset in Octave 3.8.0

```
figure; 
plot(x, y, "rx", "markersize", 10);
```

This produces a plot that more or less conforms to my expectations, except in the color of the markers. I get black "x" markers on a white field. I am expecting red markers.

If I change `"rx"` to `"ro"` I get black triangles with a dot in their centers...If I change it to `"rp"` I get the same output as `"rx"`. `"r+"` produces black crosshairs, `*` produces stars. Changing the first argument from `r` to `b` or `g` has no visible effect. Adding a `-` before the `r` produces a line plot *in red*, but with the same black markers!

this is using aquaterm on OSX 10.10.1

I also tried using fltk, but haven't gotten that to work.
After `brew install fltk` (succeeds) I restarted octave and ran my script, but got `error: __init_fltk__: not available without OpenGL and FLTK libraries`.

Comment: did you try setting your graphics_toolkit to fltk? Run `graphics_toolkit ("fltk"); figure (); plot (1:10,1:10, "rx", "markersize", 10);` . Either way, it works fine with me, using both gnuplot and fltk

Comment: see my edit. Not sure if this means I need to reinstall octave?

Comment: yes, you will need the reinstall Octave after instaling OpenGl and FLTK. The libraries need to be installed during build time.